# What's the Julia 0.7 syntax for find((x=y) & (b=a))?

Tags: julia

I've been using Julia 0.5.  The following code works, but NOT in 0.7:

```
a=[5,5,6,6]
b=[0,0,1,1]
c=find((a.==6) & (b.==1))
```

I now need to use 0.7, due to Windows/GitHub problems.  But the syntax has been altered quite considerably.  I can use 'findall' instead of 'find' if I only have one argument, e.g.

```
c=findall(a.==6)
```

but using '&' is not supported.  Does anyone know how to code this in 0.7?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is enough that you add `.` in front of `&`:

```
julia> findall((a.==6) .& (b.==1))
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 4
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks very much!